# XML loading in SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd

I'm looking to load some xml data in SSIS and am hitting a problem because of the below:

```
<One num="00034">
  <Two>some text here: http://something.com/
    <sub>&#x2014;</sub>text
    <sub>&#x2014;</sub>text
    <sub>&#x2014;</sub>text
    <sub>&#x2014;</sub>text
    <sub>&#x2014;</sub>.aspx
  </Two>
</One>
```

It's not liking the `<sub></sub>` section the creator of the xml has used to cover _ and other characters like it.

There is no accompanying  XSD file for this, (SSIS created one from a sample file we had for this data without the `<sub></sub>`)

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="One">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Two" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="num" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The error I get is:

> Error: 0xC02092AF at Data Flow Task, XML Source [960]: The XML Source was unable to process the XML data. The element "Two" cannot contain a child element. Content model is text only.

We don't want to lose the subs from there, rather keep them and tidy it up and convert to the correct char later.

I tried to set SSIS to ignore the error or redirect the row but it fails always.

Is there anyway of changing the XSD to keep this  and not split it out into another column or sub table?  not great with XMl if I'm honest!

Comment: Get the error: Error: 0xC02090CF at Data Flow Task, XML Source [960]: There was an error setting up the mapping. The 'mixed' attribute is not supported in this context.

Comment: Try `<xs:complexType mixed="true">`.

Comment: The xml source adapter doe snot support mixed content model on complex types

Comment: Sorry, then you'll have to change your content model for `Two` because it's mixed as shown.  Or, you mention, *tidy it up and convert to the correct char later.*  If you can post-process like that, maybe use different markup for `sub` than XML?   `[sub][/sub]`, for example, and then tidy *that* up later instead?

Comment: It's an external source with huge data at times,  The bosses ideally want to to come in and be automatically processed.  had hoped i could handle the issue in SSIS but may be it needs to be run through C# or something first to clean it up - thanks for your comments though!

Comment: One more idea: Have you tried using `<![CDATA[some text here: http://something.com/<sub>&#x2014;</sub>text]]>` ?

Comment: That may work but I need a method to handle the data and not change it as they will be coming from an external source.  I thought I should be able to just redirect the error row and bring it into Sql a different way but it fails the package instead of redirecting the row in SSIS